# Create a Substring from using regexp

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, string

I have a string in the format of `James Bond (007)`.
I want it to be converted to `{name: "James Bond", code: "007"}`

I can do a `for` loop and get this done, but I want to know if it easier/efficient using regexp.

Assumption is there will be no `(` or `)` in the names or codes. 
I am using nodejs here.

Comment: [`/([a-z ](?:\s*[a-z]+)*).*?(\d+)/i`](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/r1324b3g/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"James Bond (007)".replace(/(.* .*) \(?(.*)\)?/, '{name: "$1", code: "$2"}')
```

Another option, supporting a name with more than 1 space:

```
"James Bond (007)".replace(/(.*) \((.*)\)/, '{name: "$1", code: "$2"}')
```

Comment: I do have brackets separating the code from name, i.e James Bond (007)

Comment: Thank, the 2nd option works, the first option leaves a trailing ) in the code.

Comment: What is he supposed to do with the resulting string to turn it into an actual JS object that he can work with?

Comment: I don't know what he intends to do with his code. I guess that he's building some sort of a transpiler, so it'll just be a `.js` file. But if he (you) insists, he can do something like: `JSON.parse("James Bond (007)".replace(/(.*) \((.*)\)/, '{"name": "$1", "code": "$2"}'))`

Comment: I'm confused why you would build a string that then needs to be `JSON.parse`'d, when you would be better off just creating the JS object to start with. Note to mention the problems with input such as `"James" Bond (007)`.

Comment: I agree that if the OP would have wanted to convert a string to a JavaScript object your answer is better, but the OP specifically wants to convert a string to another string. The resulted string happens to look like a JS object, and they happens to work with JS, but I don't know if they intend to do that (and I'm not sure you do).

Comment: Because of some legacy code, our db data is bound to UI, and this is the data I have in database, and there is nothing much I can do about it.

Answer (score 1):

No need for a replace here, just

```js
const [, name, number] = "James Bond (007)".match(/(.*?) \((.*?)\)/);
    
console.log({name, number});
```